# Update Google Service Plugins and Unable to Install App After gradle built Successfully

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am working on Android app that uses the Firebase Database for the Storage of Data but the problem comes when app doesn't Install after the Successful built.
 [image: Here is the Image of Built Error]

Here is the Image of Error in the Gradle [image: Image 2]

Here is the code of Build.gradle

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the firebase libraries to the following:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
```

and in the top level gradle file use:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
```

Comment: These all dependancies that were added by the Firebase Automatically.

Comment: By changing these It gives the version conflict error

Comment: what error are u getting now? When you change these it should fix the "please fix the version confilict..."

Comment: It seems no errors in Logcat and In event Log It shows Gradle built successfully

Comment: In the otherBuild portion It gives the error Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.8.0.

Comment: did you update all firebase libraries? Also what android studio version are u using?

Comment: I have updated the Firebase some days ago...
and I am using the Android version 3.1.3

Comment: It seems no error If I don't use firebase with other projects. If I ue Firebase I gives the Error regarding to Gradle

Comment: did u also update google-service plugin in top level gradle file?

Comment: No; Would you like to tell me how google services plugins updated?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176793/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-usman-ali).

Answer (score 1):

Try this please, replace 27.1.1 with 26.1.0

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:26.1.0'
```

Comment: It does not resolve the Issue the android bulb told "Replace 26.1.0 with 27.1.1"

Comment: what are the targetSdkVersion ,minSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion in your project's build.gradle

Comment: Minimum 17 target 27

Comment: change them to compileSdkVersion 26
     
        targetSdkVersion 26

minSdkVersion 19 this you can let it 17 if you want